# SpannableString underline thickness

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Is there any solution for changing SpannableString underline thickness?
I want to underline only one character in a row, thats representing a cursor. I'm using SpannableString, that works perfectly, but I want to make the underline a bit thicker. Is there any solutions, that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think the underline thickness depends on your font size! you can use font style bold for your first character to have a thicker underline